# How to make all series in a chart the same color?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, rgb

How do I color all the series (lines) in a specific (selected/current) chart the same color?

I have the following, but it does nothing:

```vb
Sub Same_Color()
    Dim Chart As Chart
    Dim Series As Series

    Set Chart = ActiveChart
    Set Series = Chart.SeriesCollection(2)

    Series.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it this what you need?

```
Sub InsertChartAndFormat()
 Dim cht As ChartObject

 Set cht = Sheet1.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=10, Width:=500, Top:=50, Height:=300)

 With cht
 .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheet1.Range("A1:L2")
 .Chart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
 .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbAqua
End With

End Sub
```

BR
Bernd

Answer (score 1):

Never Mind Solved it:

```
    Sub Same_Color()  Dim Chart As Chart  Dim Series As Series

 Set Chart = ActiveChart  Set Series = Chart.SeriesCollection(2)

    For Each Series In Chart.SeriesCollection
                Series.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    
    Next

End Sub
```

Here's one for making all the series the same thickness:

```
Sub Change_all_charts()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
    Dim srs As Series
    
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        For Each ChtObj In sht.ChartObjects
            For Each srs In ChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
                srs.Format.Line.Weight = 1
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```